how to run selenium java project in docker (java+testng+maven+pageobject model)
How to run selenium java project in docker using testng,maven,page object model in it.I am unable to run it is giving error like could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG-7.9.0.and how to push and pull images and run those images in docker container
